# Filter data where col A != col B

Tags: r, dplyr, filtering

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
A <- c('X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y')
B <- c('X', 'X', 'Y', 'Z')

sample_df <- data.frame(A, B)

sample_df %>% filter(A!=B)
```

I would like to select all rows where the values of A and B don't agree (and A and B are factors); the code above throws the error "Error in Ops.factor(A, B) : level sets of factors are different"

Comment: Convert them to `character`. If you don't want to do it permanently, use `as.character(A) != as.character(B)` inside `filter()` and the conversion won't be saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Gregor's comment:

Using `dplyr`:

```
sample_df %>% 
  mutate_all(., as.character) %>%
  filter(A!=B)
```